# Cumulating the entries in a column by group and consecutively by date, in a data.table

Tags: r, optimization, data.table

My data looks as follows (package: data.table):

```
  DT <- data.table(Id = c(1,1,1,1,2,2,2,2,1,1), Time = c(0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,1,1), 
             Date = as.Date(c("20000101", "20000102", "20000103", "20000104", "20000101",
                              "20000102","20000103","20000103", "20000201", "20000201"), "%Y%m%d"),
             Price = c(0,1,0,3,2,0,4,5,2,3))
 >DT
    Id Time       Date Price
 1:  1    0 2000-01-01     0
 2:  1    0 2000-01-02     1
 3:  1    0 2000-01-03     0
 4:  1    0 2000-01-04     3
 5:  2    0 2000-01-01     2
 6:  2    0 2000-01-02     0
 7:  2    0 2000-01-03     4
 8:  2    0 2000-01-03     5
 9:  1    1 2000-02-01     2
10:  1    1 2000-02-01     3
```

`Price` needs to be cumulated by `Time` and `Id`, and in the order of `Date`, so that the output to look as follows:

```
    Id Time       Date Price Cum.price
 1:  1    0 2000-01-01     0         0
 2:  1    0 2000-01-02     1         1
 3:  1    0 2000-01-03     0         1
 4:  1    0 2000-01-04     3         4
 5:  2    0 2000-01-01     2         2
 6:  2    0 2000-01-02     0         2
 7:  2    0 2000-01-03     4         6
 8:  2    0 2000-01-03     5        11
 9:  1    1 2000-02-01     2         2
10:  1    1 2000-02-01     3         5
```

Further information: The data.table is filled to contain 1 entry per day per `Id` per `Time`. There are no missing values in `Price`.

I can think of many ways to solve this problem using loops, but is there an extremely efficient way of doing this with data.table that will work quickly for large data.tables?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can group by 'Time' and 'Id' columns and get the `cumsum` of 'Price' column `order`ered by 'Date' column

```
DT[order(Date), Cum.price :=cumsum(Price), by = .(Time, Id)]
DT
#     Id Time       Date Price Cum.price
# 1:  1    0 2000-01-01     0         0
# 2:  1    0 2000-01-02     1         1
# 3:  1    0 2000-01-03     0         1
# 4:  1    0 2000-01-04     3         4
# 5:  2    0 2000-01-01     2         2
# 6:  2    0 2000-01-02     0         2
# 7:  2    0 2000-01-03     4         6
# 8:  2    0 2000-01-03     5        11
# 9:  1    1 2000-02-01     2         2
#10:  1    1 2000-02-01     3         5
```